# Django 'dict' object has no attribute 'META' error when using an API

Tags: django, api, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from an API but have been getting the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'META'` when I try to print it. I am using Requests module for this. Here is the code:

```
url = "https://coronavirus-map.p.rapidapi.com/v1/summary/region"

    querystring = {"region":"Bangladesh"}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "coronavirus-map.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "leaving this out :P"
    }

    request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

    print(request.text)
```

Everything works on Postman. Can anyone help?

Comment: `params` looks suspicious here, isn't `json=` or `data=`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all I had to do is remove the '.text' from the print command. I don't know why I had to do that though. Would be helpful if someone could tell.

So the change was:

```
print(request)
```

Comment: Or .json() from the lite above. Having the variable request be a dict seems misleading.

Comment: So, the reason for the error is that .json() from the response object returns a dict in this case. (It could also potentially be a list, depending on the JSON data.) And then on the line below you try to print the attribute .text from the response object, but on the dict instead.